# How to strip out seconds and milliseconds from Kusto datetime

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I am trying to restrict the kusto datetime to yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm. However, I see that:

```
print todatetime((format_datetime(datetime(2015-12-14 00:03:04.12345), 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm')))
and
print todatetime((format_datetime(datetime(2015-12-14 12:03:04.12345), 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm')))
```

both return 2015-12-14 12:03:00.0000000. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 4):

a `datetime`-typed value will always include milli/micro/seconds (even if their value is `0`). `todatetime()` always returns a `datetime`-typed value.

if you want to format a `datetime`-typed value using a specific format, you'll have to keep it as a `string`, and use the `format_datetime()` function as you did above.

```
print string_value = format_datetime(datetime(2015-12-14 00:03:04.12345), 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `HH` instead of `hh`.
You can try this:

```
print todatetime((format_datetime(datetime(2015-12-14 12:03:04.12345), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm')))
```